# Moment.js to format dateString

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Need to use Moment.js to format the below Date string.

**Wed Sept 01 2017 04:33:01 GMT+0400 (+04)**

I tried to use below but it didn't work

```
moment(e.dateVale, 'D MMMM D YYYY, hh:mm:ss a')
```

I  referred http://momentjs.com/ but couldn't make it work.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What didn't work, what's the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `new Date` for creating a Date object from the String you're passing and then will enable you to use moment for formatting that Date object.

See this:

```
console.log(moment(new Date('Wed Sept 03 2017 06:33:01 GMT+0400 (+04)')).format( 'D MMMM D YYYY, hh:mm:ss a'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
console.log(moment('Wed Sep 06 2017 04:33:01 GMT+0400 (+04)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z').utc())
```

Day and date combination in the string provided by you is not correct and will give following error.

```
moment.invalid(/* Wed Sept 01 2017 04:33:01 GMT+0400 (+04) */)
```